# Django nginx 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-413

After logining the admin page it is returning 413 error (Request Entity Too Large). Than I added client_max_body_size to my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and restarted nginx, but it didnt helped :(
I know that this error is a common one, but I had to ask this question because there is no more information that about client_max_body_size.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    client_max_body_size 100;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your settings.py file

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 5242880 # 5 MB
```

if this doesn't work, in your nginx.config file try

```
client_max_body_size 100;
```

to this:

```
 client_max_body_size 200M;
```

you can refer [this](https://zoejoyuliao.medium.com/the-problem-you-may-face-when-you-upload-a-big-file-to-a-nginx-django-application-413-request-4ae9b50874a5)

Comment: Had it fixed the problem?